# Bash for loop parsed as single string

Tags: bash

Why is my bash code:

```
for file in "production/features/*.fea"; do
    echo "FILE"
    echo $file
done
```

outputting:

```
FILE
production/features/italics.stylistic.fea production/features/lookups.fea production/features/uprights.fea production/features/uprights.stylistic.fea
```

I'd expect it to print:

```
FILE
production/features/italics.stylistic.fea 
FILE
production/features/lookups.fea 
FILE
production/features/uprights.fea 
FILE
production/features/uprights.stylistic.fea
```

This must be something super stupid, but as bash beginner I can't seem to figure out where it's going wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Inside quotes, the `*` will not expand to a list of files. To use such a wildcard successfully, it must be outside of quotes.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
for file in production/features/*.fea; do
    echo "FILE"
    echo "$file"

    # More information about why to use printf below
    # printf "FILE\n${file}\n"
done
```

---

**Note:** As @Inian suggested; you should quote the `$file` variable to prevent any misbehaviour caused by the filename. Read more about when to quote bash variable [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/131767/339347).

This way, `for()` could be just a single `printf`;

```sh
printf "FILE\n${file}\n"
```

<sup>[Use `printf` for portability reasons](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/65803/why-is-printf-better-than-echo/65819)</sup>

[Try it on Repl.it](https://repl.it/join/jclidjff-0stone0)

Comment: Including data (e.g. filenames) in the `printf` command's format string (first argument) is a bad practice, since it'll behave weirdly for certain characters in the data. You should only have formatting info in the format string, and other data should go in separate arguments, with directives like `%s` in the format string to interpolate the data. In this case, use `printf 'FILE\n%s\n' "$file"`

Comment: or `printf  "FILE\n%s\n" production/features/*.fea`

Comment: Take a look at (for example) [this](https://superuser.com/a/1054817/1003439) post, you can just add the wildcard after the var.

Comment: @0stone0 cheers, just realized I was being silly ;)